# Display PDF content in terminal (just like using "less" with txt)

Tags: pdf, terminal.app

I was just wondering if there is a way to display content of a PDF file inside terminal, just like doing `less file.txt` but with PDF files.

Answer (score 7):

The program `pdftotext`, which comes as a part of `xpdf`, can convert a PDF to text. There is also a program called `lesspipe`, which can be set as a preprocessor for `less` so that if you have `pdftotext` or something like it installed, you can just use `less` with PDF (and many other types of files).

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that allow to extract text from PDF files ([Google for it](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=extract+text+from+pdf&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g10)) but IMHO there are cases where this will simply be not possible (imagine a PDF that contains only images).

Answer (score -2):

You can use `less` to view pdf text in terminal. It works quite well but garbles do happen.

Comment: At least use `strings filename.pdf | less`

Comment: That won't work at all if the streams are compressed.